# Vue asnyc await over several layers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently building a small Vue JS app. I'm using a Simple State Management with Reactivity API to cache data between pages. But I also have some functions built in. One function is to fetch data from the backend. For the API communication I created a helper class that talks to the API. For example, a product list should be displayed. The component has a method that calls a store.js method. The store.js method then calls a method from the helper class. I work with fetch and async await. To display a list in the component view at the end of the day I need to pass the data from the helper class to the component using asnyc await. Now my question.  Is this approach a crime against javascript? **Is there a better solution for this?**

**The three relevant files.**

```js
// PageComponent
<script>
import { store } from '../helpers/store'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      store,
      list: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      store.getData()
    }
  },
}
</script>


// store.js
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import  { comhelper } from "./comhelper";

export const store = reactive({
    brand: "",

    async getData() {
        return await comhelper.getData();
    }
});


// comhelper.js
export const comhelper = {
    async getSurveyData() {
        const d = await fetch('/data/db.json');        
        return await d.json();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code descriptions are ambiguous and don't work. You've seen your own code, others doesn't. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Questions using terms like "better" and "best practice" are only answerable if you can clearly and specifically articulate what you mean by "better" and "best practice" in the context of *your specific problem.*

Comment: "Better solution" is ambiguous at best. Does your current approach work?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, the code works fine!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I add some Code for better understanding. Thank u!

Comment: Your code is an example of abstraction, a central principle of object oriented programming.  I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: What exactly happens in the component? It's unclear from the example how data is handled. I suspect that a store is useless abstraction here. You can compare your implementation with Pinia store, for example. Notice that store methods update data on a store and return a promise, so a caller could chain it to know that an action is complete, but data is kept in a store itself

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks to your comments and the time between the question and reading the comments, I understood that the approach is not a "crime against JS" and that one can deal with promises in this way. Big thanks!